# NoReverseMatch at Reverse for 'url-name' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: django

everyone. Here is the problem:

I'm the 'NoReverseMatch' message when i try to enter localhost/condominio/generate

> NoReverseMatch at /condominio/generate
> Reverse for 'generate-details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['condominio/generate/(?P<loc_id>[^/]+)$']

Here are my code parts:

urls.py:

```
path('generate', views.generate, name='generate-section'),

path('generate/<str:loc_id>', views.generate_details, name='generate-details'),
```

views.py:

````
def generate(request):

  loc = Locatario.objects.order_by('unidade_id')
  return render(request, 'calccondominio/generate.html', context)```

def generate_details(request, loc_id):

  loc = get_object_or_404(Locatario, pk=loc_id)
  ctr = loc.contrato_set.get(pk=loc_id)
  return render(request, 'calccondominio/generate_details.html', {'loc':loc, 'ctr':ctr})
````

generate.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

  

    <div class="container">
        <div class="card w-100">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Unidades atualmente ocupadas:</h5>
            {% for l in loc %}
              <a href="{% url 'generate-details' locid.id %}">{{l.unidade}}</a>
            {%endfor%}
      
          </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 

  

{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the object o fthe `Loctario` in your template is `l`, not `locid</s>`, you thus should rewrite it to:

```
{% for l in loc %}
    <a href="{% url 'generate-details' l.id %}">{{l.unidade}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

You can also use the `.pk` to obtain the primary key, which might be better if you perhaps later change the name of the id:

```
{% for l in loc %}
    <a href="{% url 'generate-details' l.pk %}">{{l.unidade}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.